# Como remover o erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public'

Tags: php, pdo

Olá gostaria de saber como posso tirar esse erro da minha query

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
          <?php



          public    function RetornaAtualizacoes(){

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    try {
        $Query = "SELECT 
                s.setor,
                s.usuario,
                s.hd,
                s.memoria,
                s.cd,
                s.placam,
                s.host,
                s.monitor,
                s.nobreak,
                s.placar,
                s.placav
        FROM setor

                  ";
        include_once $_SESSION['pmodel'].'Projetos/index.php';
               $p_sql = MysqlConnection::getInstance()->prepare($Query);

                $_retorno = array(); 

                if($p_sql->execute()) {
                    while ($_result = $p_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
                        $_retorno[] = $_result; 
                    }
                }

                return $_retorno;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }


            }
        ?>


             <div>
                <table width="100%" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" BORDER="1" class='tabelaProt'>
                                <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                             <th>Setor</th>
                                             <th>Usuário</th>
                                             <th>Hd</th>
                                             <th>Memória</th>
                                             <th>Processador</th>
                                             <th>Cd/Dvd</th>
                                             <th>Hd</th>
                                             <th>Memória</th>
                                             <th>Setor</th>
                                             <th>Usuário</th>
                                             <th>Hd</th>
                                             <th>Memória</th>
                                        </tr>
                                </thead>
                        <tbody>         
  <?php
               $setor=$_POST['setor'];
                $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
                $hd=$_POST['hd'];
                $memoria=$_POST['memoria'];
                $processador=$_POST['processador'];
                $cd=$_POST['cd'];
                $placam=$_POST['placam'];
                $host=$_POST['host'];
                $monitor=$_POST['monitor'];
                $nobreak=$_POST['nobreak'];
                $placar=$_POST['placar'];
                $placav=$_POST['placav'];

         $data           = $_POST["data"];
        $codusuario     = $_POST["codusuario"];
        $cRelatorios = new cRelatorios();
          $relatorio = $cRelatorios->RetornaAtualizacoes();    

                   if(!empty($relatorio)){

                   foreach($relatorio as  $value){
              // echo "<pre>"; print_r($value); exit;
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td><center>". $value[""] ."</center></td>";
                 echo "<td><center>". $value[""] ."</center></td>";
                 echo "<td><center>". $value[""] ."</center></td>";
                echo "<td>". $value[""] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $value[""] ."</td>";
               echo count($relatorio);//Quero que imprima só uma vez dentro do <td>
               echo "</tr >";

                                   }
    }


     ?>
```

Comment: O que acha de remover o public da função?

Comment: ficaria só function @AckLay

Comment: quando eu tiro aparece Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'cRelatorios' not found in C: @AckLay

Comment: eu retirei e apareceu o Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'cRelatorios' not found in C: @Miguel tentei de tudo e nada

Comment: Tem que tirar o public mesmo, esse erro aí de classe cRelatorios não encontrada é pq vc esqueceu de importar ela, ou ela existe mesmo? Em questões futuras não poste o print do erro, basta copiar e colar o texto aqui, é bem mais fácil de ler em alguns dispositivos ou de alguém copiar no google pra te ajudar.